# Any way to install old Samsung Printer SCX-4521F to my MacOS Ventura?

Tags: printing, ventura

I tried many drivers to install Samsung SCX-4521F connected via USB but cannot succeeded.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried the drivers at https://www.openprinting.org/printers ? There doesn't seem to be one for your exact model, but it uses SPL, so any Samsung driver should work; possibly with a little modification.

Comment: What drivers have you tried so far. Where did you get them from? How did you try to install them? What error messages did you get? Your question cannot be answered without the detail of what you've already tried.

Answer (score 2):

It is very unlikely you will find any printer drivers for a modern operating system for this particular printer. This is because it is a host-based printer, which means the rendering is done on the host rather than on the printer itself. Below is a small snippet of the technical specifications page for the printer, as you can see, it uses its own language SPL, which is host-based.

[image]

If you visit the [HP Support page](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/samsung-scx-4521-laser-multifunction-printer-series/model/19135313), you will find that the most recent drives is for Mavericks and it is likely only 32-bit being that this printer is so old there’s been no further development on it especially since HP bought them out.

[image]

It may be possible to extend the life of this printer by connecting it to a Windows or older, OSX computer and sharing it across a network.